# Tic Tac Toe in Python 3.x

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, game, tic-tac-toe

I made Tic Tac Toe in Python. Standard code review, please tell me ways to improve. I am very new to Python, so please do not criticize very roundabout ways. Thanks.

```
board = []
for x in range(3):
    board.append([' '] * 3)
def print_board(board):
    x = 1
    print('    A   B   C')
    print()
    dashes = 0
    for row in board:
        print(x, ' ', ' | '.join(row))
        if dashes <= 1:
            print(' ', ' -'*6)
            dashes += 1
        x += 1
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]
print('This is Tic Tac Toe.')
print('Player 1 will be X and Player 2 will be O.')
win = False
while win != True:
    print()
    print_board(board)
    print()
    while True:
        p1 = input('Player 1, where would you like to place a X? ').lower()  
        try:
            p1_col_let = split(p1)[0]
            p1_row = int(split(p1)[1])
            p1_col = int(ord(p1_col_let) - 96)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid format.')
        if board[p1_row - 1][p1_col - 1] != ' ':
            print('That spot is already taken.')
        else:
            break
    while True:
        p2 = input('Player 2, where would you like to place an O? ').lower()
        try:
            p2_col_let = split(p2)[0]
            p2_row = int(split(p2)[1])
            p2_col = int(ord(p2_col_let) - 96)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid format.')
        if board[p2_row - 1][p2_col - 1] != ' ' or p2_row == p1_row and p2_col == p1_col:
            print('That spot is already taken.')
        else:
            break
    board[p1_row - 1][p1_col - 1] = 'X'
    board[p2_row - 1][p2_col - 1] = 'O'
    a1 = board[0][0]
    a2 = board[1][0]
    a3 = board[2][0]
    b1 = board[0][1]
    b2 = board[1][1]
    b3 = board[2][1]
    c1 = board[0][2]
    c2 = board[1][2]
    c3 = board[2][2]
    if a1 == 'X' and a2 == 'X' and a3 == 'X' or b1 == 'X' and b2 == 'X' and b3 == 'X' or c1 == 'X' and c2 == 'X' and c3 == 'X' or a1 == 'X' and b1 == 'X' and c1 == 'X' or a2 == 'X' and b2 == 'X' and c2 == 'X' or a3 == 'X' or b3 == 'X' or c3 == 'X' or a1 == 'X' and b2 == 'X' and c3 == 'X' or c1 == 'X' and b2 == 'X' and a3 == 'X':
        print()
        print_board(board)
        print()
        print('Player 1 wins!')
        win = True
    if a1 == 'O' and  a2 == 'O' and a3 == 'O' or b1 == 'O' and b2 == 'O' and b3 == 'O' or c1 == 'O' and c2 == 'O' and c3 == 'O' or a1 == 'O' and b1 == 'O' and c1 == 'O' or a2 == 'O' and b2 == 'O' and c2 == 'O' or a3 == 'O' or b3 == 'O' or c3 == 'O' or a1 == 'O' and b2 == 'O' and c3 == 'O' or c1 == 'O' and b2 == 'O' and a3 == 'O':
        print()
        print_board(board)
        print()
        print('Player 2 wins!')
        win = True
    if a1 != ' ' and a2 != ' ' and a3 != ' ' and b1 != ' ' and b2 != ' ' and b3 != ' ' and c1 != ' ' and c2 != ' ' and c3 != ' ':
        print('It\'s a tie!')
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming of variables is perfect and you are following the python convention - and that is really good because it makes the code easier to read.

I've executed the code and I've noticed that when you insert an invalid input two things may happen

1. Input "1A"; Output:  "Invalid format. That spot is already taken."
2. Input "X"; Output: Application crash

So that's a bug that we need to address.

Biggest problems in the code are

1. Use of global scope (that is, putting variables outside of methods)
2. Code duplication

About the first one, we need to put everything inside a method. This is better because you will constraint the scope of variables, make things easier to read and the intention of each line will be clearer. Also it's always better to define all the methods at the beginning and then the code that needs to be executed (that should be in a `main` method, normally).

If I would do it I would create a `Board` `class` but there is no particular reason to use Object Oriented Programming here so I will try to follow your way of reasoning.

At first we are initializing the board so

```
def create_board():
    board = []
    for _ in range(3):
        board.append([' '] * 3)
    return board
```

You were not actually using the `x` variable in the loop so I've renamed to _, which is a convention to say that you're not actually interested in that variable. To have magic numbers, like 3 in this case, is bad because someday you may ask "Why 3?". Now it pretty obvious, but it might get more complex, an easy way to fix that is

```
def create_board(size=3):
    board = []
    for _ in range(size):
        board.append([' '] * size)
    return board
```

The behavior is the same but now everybody will know what is 3. Is quite useless to have a parametric sized board, because you can play Tic-Tac-Toe only with 3x3 boards, but I'm using that as a way to show you how to be prepared for later improvements (Connect-Four? :) ).

Now let's print the board. You're code was actually pretty good, I wanted to add a variable size board because, in your code, you're using the fact that the board is 3x3 in many hidden ways. (For example `if dashes <= 1:`).

```
def print_board(board):
    board_size = len(board)
    cols = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'), ord('A') + board_size)]
    print()
    print(f"    {'   '.join(cols)}")
    print()
    row_label = 1
    for row in board:
        print(row_label, ' ', ' | '.join(row))
        if row_label < board_size:
            print(' ', ' -' * (2 * board_size))
        row_label += 1
    print()
```

`x` became `row_label` because that what it is. I've added the `print()` before and after, because they are, in fact, part of the print of the board.

The `split` method is not useful, characters in `string` can be already accessed by index. So we can get rid of it and the game will work as before.

As I was saying, there a few duplications in the code, and they are in the game loop, let's try to refactor that part, starting from the user input:

```
def ask_value(player_name, player_symbol, board):
    board_size = len(board)
    while True:
        player_input = input(f"{player_name}, where would you like to place a {player_symbol}").lower()
        try:
            col_let = player_input[0]
            row = int(player_input[1]) - 1  # [REVIEW COMMENT] we use 0 based indexes, the user doesn't
            col = int(ord(col_let) - ord('a'))
            if (not (0 <= col < board_size)) or (not (0 <= row < board_size)):
                raise ValueError("Index out of board")
            if board[row][col] != ' ':
                print('That spot is already taken.')
                raise ValueError("Spot already taken")
            return row, col
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print('Invalid format.')
```

This method will replace the duplication of code for the input. I've added a range check to avoid going outside of the board and now the input validation bug is fixed.
Avoid to use non-zero based index; it is not the normal approach and you will get rid of all those `- 1` all over the code.

The part where you check who won is a bit cumbersome and is using more developer time than cpu time (how long it took to check all the boolean conditions? :) ) also it doesn't scale with the board size (I understand that this wasn't a problem for you).

I'm not going to write how to check who won but I will suggest you a way to structure your code:

```
def check_winner(board, symbol):
   if check_rows(board, symbol):
       return symbol
   if check_cols(board, symbol):
       return symbol
   if check_diagonals(board, symbol):
       return symbol
   if check_tie():
       return '#'
   return None
```

So the main loop will become:

```
def main():
    board = create_board()
    print('This is Tic Tac Toe.')
    print('Player 1 will be X and Player 2 will be O.')
    players = [{"name": "Player 1", "symbol": "X"}, {"name": "Player 2", "symbol": "O"}]
    end = False
    while not end:  # [REVIEW COMMENT] this is more pythonish than "win != True"
        print_board(board)
        for player in players:
            symbol = player["symbol"]
            row, col = ask_value(player["name"], symbol, board)
            board[row][col] = symbol
            winning_symbol = check_winner(board, symbol)
            if winning_symbol == '#':
                print("It is a tie!")
                end = True
                break
            elif winning_symbol:
                print(f"{player['name']} has won!!")
                end = True
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How does the check winner work? Don't I still have to write out all the booleans?

Comment: @user Yes and no. You have to check each cell to be sure whether someone has won or not, but you don't have to write down each cell. Imagine that you are playing Connect Four in a gigantic board, how would you do that? Tic-Tac-Toe is easier because you can just check that the whole row/column/diagonal is equal to a symbol.